# visudo syntax error

Tags: linux, sudo

What am I doing wrong here as this line is making visudo fail

dhiller2        ALL= ALL, !NSHELLS, !NSU      NOPASSWD: ALL

this line works

dhiller2        ALL= ALL, !NSHELLS, !NSU

How to fix this?

and yes, I know there are ways to get around this...this is just to remind our admins that policy is not sudo su - and you should be using sudo to run all commands.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: So, you aim is, that user dhiller2 should be able to run all commands on this machine and shouldn't be asked for the password and sudn't be able to do `sudo su -`... is that right ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this.

dhiller2 ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL, !NSHELLS, !NSU

It will work. Tested on my machine itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional comma after !NSU.

The line below passed visudo but I don't know if it has the effect you want.

dhiller2 ALL= ALL, !NSHELLS, !NSU, NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: hmmmm, it parses now but now it no longer denies me access to doing "sudo su -" anymore :(.